# Error running notification service

Tags: neovim

I installed the new version nvim nightly and get the following error:

> Error running notification service: ...l/share/nvim/lazy/nvim-notify/lua/notify/stages/util.lua:150: attempt to index a number value

Can someone help me?

Comment: That looks like a plugin error

Comment: please report to the plugin repository

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from a plugin [folke/noice.nvim](https://github.com/folke/noice.nvim). Uninstall the plugin and re-install it. This worked for me.
OR delete the file `util.lua` in `~/.local/share/nvim/lazy/nvim-notify/lua/notify/stages/util.lua`. this will cause nvim ask you to uninstall and re-install noice.nvim during start.